# How to select input element by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 `input` fields:

```
<input type="text" id="fruits" data-role="tagsinput" />
<input type="text" id="animals" />
<input type="password" id="pass" />
```

I want to apply bootstrap-tags to the `input` with the id of "fruits". The following does not work:

```
var myInput = $('#fruits');
```

The only way I'm able to select the element is by doing this:

```
var myInput = $('input');
```

However, that will cause all 3 inputs to be selected.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dirty_penguin/xfh46ppz/6/

What is the correct way to select the `input` element by it's `id` attribute?

Comment: The fiddle had JavaScript set to "onLoad". I changed it to "no wrap - in <body>" and it worked on the spot.

Comment: thanks, that worked :)